# How to filter based on another model in Django ModelViewSet?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I currently have a `SiteViewSet` using `ModelViewSet` that can list, retrieve, create, and update sites from the model `Site`.

I want to add a filter to the same `SiteViewSet` that lists all the site objects where `is_active` is True - but this condition is based on the `AdminConfiguration` model.

I was not able to find how to implement a filter in `ModelViewSet` based on conditions of another model. Is the filtered endpoint `/v1/site/?is_active=True` possible to implement in the same `SiteViewSet` or should I create a separate view to achieve this via the more flexible `APIView`?

`SiteViewSet`:

```
class SiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Site
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    serializer_class = SiteSerializer
    queryset = Site.objects.all()
```

`Site` Model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        unique=True)
    domain_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

`AdminConfiguration` Model:

```
class AdminConfiguration(models.Model):
    site = models.OneToOneField(
        Site,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    always_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subscription_ends = models.DateTimeField(
        default=set_default_expiration)

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        active_status = self.always_active or self.subscription_ends > timezone.now()
        return active_status
```

Comment: What is the link about the two models ? are they linked by a field or not ?

Comment: @Rvector the 2 models share the same primary key (`id` of the Site model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In DRF filter based on another model is the same that filter against a model field. And you achieve this by override the get_queryset method like this :**

*we assume that you have declared your OneToOneField like :*
`site = models.OneToOneField(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='admin_config')`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Site.objects.filter(admin_config__is_active=True)
```

*.filter(related_model_name__field=value)*

**NB :** Your `is_active` field is a property ! So i have never tested with `@property` field of a model. But it work fine with standard fields.
Don't also forget to remove the `queryset` attribute if you override `get_queryset` method. One of them, not both.

Comment: thank you for this tip! I was able to make it work